# Does Qt have an additive blend mode?

Tags: qt, qpainter

QPainter has many composition modes but none called additive. I'm interested because additive blending is used all the time in games for lighting / particles whatever.
The overlay mode is the only one that had something like the effect of lighting.

**EDIT:** I figured it out, heres how you can efficiently make different coloured lights in Qt.

In constructor or where ever, not in paint event:

```
light = QPixmap("light.png");
QPainter pix(light);
pix.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Overlay);
pix.fillRect(light.rect(), QColor(255, 0, 0, 255)); // colorize the light in any color
```

Paint Event:

```
// Do drawing, e.g. a background
p.drawPixmap(0, 0, QPixmap("background.png"));

// draw the lighting
p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Plus);
p.drawPixmap(100, 100, light);
```

You can reuse the same pixmap as much as you like and draw it with different opacity or size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `QPainter::CompositionMode_Plus` says:

> Both the alpha and color of the source and destination pixels are added together.

Comment: Yeah. I think thats it. They should say aka additive mode in the documentation. I figured out how to make everything blend together the way I wanted.